# Filing report on user

Tags: support, flagging

I'm not sure how to flag a user, but https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/10072/user10072 seems to have been just posting a spam answer in several questions. I know I just confirmed flags for at least 2 of his/her posts. Is there a correct way of bringing users like this to diamond's attention, or is flagging each spam answer the correct way to go?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 9):

Flagging each spam answer would probably be sufficient.

You can't *directly* flag a user, but you can flag any of the user's posts with a custom flag and explain the situation.

Comment: sounds good.  I just didn't want their answers to pull dead questions up, and give false/misleading info out/hurt the site's image.

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, spam flags are handled a bit specially on the SE network, and enough spam flags will automatically hide posts by that user and give a heads up to the moderation team to take a look at it. This is usually done very quickly (the same user posted a similar message on academia, and perhaps Super User as well).

If you see spam, flag it, and then if you feel so compelled, hop in to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) and just say *"Spam:"* and post a link to the question (it will 'onebox' the post in question so we can all click directly to it).

If the post still exists in 15 minutes despite this, you can raise a custom flag for the moderators (as Jim suggests), and/or you can hop in to [Meta Chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) which usually has users who can handle it if you link to it there. This should rarely be necessary, since most of these sorts of posts are caught and dealt with very very quickly.

Comment: ummm...I'm somewhat confused.  I asked this back in July, Jim edited it 8 hours ago, and there is another answer?  Thank you for explaining how spam flags work, I was unaware they were handled in such a way.

Comment: I didn't realize it was just an edit, woops! Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem.  Just confused me why I was getting notifications on something many months old, haha.